# Why does cursor move to start of input field when value is changed dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks, state

I have an input field in my react application like below. suggestedTerm and searchTerm are coming from component's state. searchTerm state is being set in onChange handle. suggestedTerm state is being set when i navigate up or down in autocomplete suggestion list.

```
<input value={suggestedTerm || searchTerm}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      onFocus={() => {
        setShowFlyout(true);
        clearActiveSuggestion();
      }}
      onKeyDown={handleInputKeyDown}
      ref={searchInput}
    />
```

Here through onKeyDown handler, i am handling up and down arrow key events to navigate through the autosuggestion suggestions list that is being produced while keeping the focus on the input field. That was done basically to cater accesibility.

The requirement is to set the selected suggestion on the input field as we navigate through the autosuggestion list. However, the issue i am facing here is that my cursor moves to the beginning of the input field whenever i set suggestedTerm state which in return sets the input field's value while navigating up using up arrow key. This does not happen when i navigate through down key.

Attaching here my up key and down key logic

```
if ((e.key === "ArrowUp" || e.keyCode === 38) && !isEmpty(suggestions)) {
  const focusedItem = getActiveSuggestion();
  const index = focusedItem[0].index - 1;
  if (!isEmpty(focusedItem) && focusedItem[0] && focusedItem[0].index > 0) {
    setActiveSuggestion(index);
  } else {
    //Clear active suggestions if up is pressed while focus is on first element
    clearActiveSuggestion();
  }

if ((e.key === "ArrowDown" || e.keyCode === 40) && !isEmpty(suggestions)) {
  const focusedItem = getActiveSuggestion();
  //Set first suggestion active
  if (isEmpty(focusedItem)) setActiveSuggestion(0);
  else {
    if (
      !isEmpty(focusedItem) &&
      focusedItem[0] &&
      focusedItem[0].index < (suggestions && suggestions.length - 1)
    ) {
      setActiveSuggestion(focusedItem[0].index + 1);
    } else {
      //Set first suggestion active when focus is on last item already and down key is pressed
      setActiveSuggestion(0);
    }
  }
}

const clearActiveSuggestion = () => {
setSuggestions(suggestions.map(suggestion => ({ ...suggestion, active: false })));
setSuggestedTerm("");};

const getActiveSuggestion = () => {
return suggestions.filter(suggestion => suggestion.active);};

const setActiveSuggestion = activeItemIndex => {
const updatedSuggestion = suggestions.map(suggestion => {
    if(activeItemIndex === suggestion.index)
      setSuggestedTerm(suggestion.dq);
    return {...suggestion, active: activeItemIndex === suggestion.index};
});
setSuggestions(updatedSuggestion);};
```

First, i do not understand why my input field is setting cursor to start of the input field even though i am changing the state and state change should reset value of input field.
Second, i searched a number of ways to manually set the cursor using setSelection method and manually setting input field's value using ref but nothing is changing the behavior.

Can anybody figure out the issue here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the root cause. Actually, it is a default behavior of an input field to take cursor to start of the string in an input field when up arrow is pressed on it so i simply added

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

and that prevented the default behavior of the input field to move the cursor. It had nothing to do with how i am setting the state or setting the selectionRange of the input manually.